# How to show a specific icon in a table row?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table and each row has an icon. When you click on the icon, it should show another icon that was hidden. My problem is that when I click on this icon, it always changes the first row, not the row of the icon that I have clicked.

This is my function:

```
$("#myTable").on('click', 'tbody tr #editAction', function () { 
    $('#deleteAction').show();
    $('#editAction').hide();
});
```

Comment: You are using id selector witch always selects the first element in dom tree found by id.
Try to use a class selector.

Comment: Ideally, Id is supposed to be unique. That is why, when you `$('#deleteAction')` it is going to find the first occurrence of any element with Id deleteAction.

Comment: It's not ideally @Nasim duplciating id's in the markup breaks the HTML specification. So you should **never** duplicate ids. If you do, don't expect anything in jquery (or even browsers) to work correctly. You need to fix your markup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Selector for duplicate ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850471/jquery-selector-for-duplicate-ids)

Answer (score 1):

The attribute [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique in a document, you can use [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead. You also have to target the current element with `this` keyword.

**Demo:**

```js
$("#myTable").on('click', 'tbody tr .editAction', function () {
    $(this).closest('.deleteAction').show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td> 
      <td>50</td>
      <td class="deleteAction">delete</td>
      <td class="editAction">edit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td> 
      <td>94</td>
      <td class="deleteAction">delete</td>
      <td class="editAction">edit</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#deleteAction')` results in a global search in the DOM that returns the first element that matches the id, ensure each id in the DOM is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement class selector as following

```
$("#myTable").on('click', 'tbody tr .editAction', function (e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).find('.deleteAction').show();
    $(e.currentTarget).find('.editAction').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `$('#deleteAction')` will return the first element that matches that id. Instead of using IDs, you should use classes. Classes can be used more than once on a page, whereas IDs should not be.

The code below will hide the clicked `.editAction`, then show the `.deleteAction` from the same row.

```
$("#myTable").on('click', 'tbody tr .editAction', function () {

    $(this).hide().closest("tr").find(".deleteAction").show();

});
```

HTML wise, you will need to replace `id="#editAction"` with `class="editAction"`:

```
<tr>
    <td><img class="editAction"></td>
    <td><img class="deleteAction"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>
            <button class="deleteAction">delete</button>
            <br>
            <button class="editAction">edit</button>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>
            <button class="deleteAction">delete</button>
            <br>
            <button class="editAction">edit</button>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>
            <button class="deleteAction">delete</button>
            <br>
            <button class="editAction">edit</button>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.editAction', function () {
        var cur = $(this);
        cur.parent().find('.editAction').hide();
        cur.parent().find('.deleteAction').show();

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers. As [already discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56681795/ajax-post-passing-null-to-controller/56681938#comment99929816_56681938)

Comment: Posted what with code? You need to explain **what you've done and why**. Just a blob of code is not very useful and will likely just attract more downvotes. BTW if you keep posting low quality answers you may well get an [answer ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)