# How set to default values in a table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an Html table where I have one button in each row. When I click on a button, it shows 2 buttons more and this disappears. I'm trying to hide the showed buttons when I click on the button from other row but I don't know how do it.

This is my function code

```
$("#myTable").on('click', 'tbody tr #editAction', function (e) {    
  $(this).hide().closest("tr").find("#deleteAction").show();
  $(this).hide().closest("tr").find("#saveAction").show();
});
```

Comment: __Identifiers in HTML must be unique.__ use common css class then use class selector i.e. `'.yourClassName'`

Comment: Please also add the HTML code.

Comment: When you click on a button, two new buttons should appear and all other buttons should disappear? So the original button on the same row and the buttons on all other rows should disappear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show a specific icon in a table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56682064/how-to-show-a-specific-icon-in-a-table-row)

Comment: You've already asked this question and had it answered. Please don't ask duplicate questions

Comment: The title is misleading. I was searching for an ability to add default values when the value of the cell is empty

Answer (score 0):

You should change the id to class, if you use id, only first row will apply event.
Change your code to

```
 $(".editAction").click(function (e) {    
     $("tr").find(".deleteAction").hide();
     $("tr").find(".saveAction").hide();
     $("tr").find(".editAction").show();
      //show delete and save
     $(this).closest("tr").find(".deleteAction").show();
     $(this).closest("tr").find(".saveAction").show();
     //hide edit button
     $(this).hide();
});
```

```js
$(".editAction").click(function (e) {    
 $("tr").find(".deleteAction").hide();
 $("tr").find(".saveAction").hide();
 $("tr").find(".editAction").show();
  //show delete and save
  $(this).closest("tr").find(".deleteAction").show();
  $(this).closest("tr").find(".saveAction").show();
  //hide edit button
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.deleteAction, .saveAction{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>
    <button class='editAction'>Edit</button>
    </td>
    <td>
    <button class='deleteAction'>Delete</button>
    </td>
    <td>
    <button class='saveAction'>Save</button>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
       <td>
    <button class='editAction'>Edit</button>
    </td>
    <td>
    <button class='deleteAction'>Delete</button>
    </td>
    <td>
    <button class='saveAction'>Save</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
 
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Classes on button and add an event handler to the first button.
1. First hide(2nd and 3rd) all button in all rows.
2. Show the all first button of all rows.
3. Show (2nd and 3rd) of current row.
4. Hide (1st) of current row.
Template HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".js-btn2").hide();
  $(".js-btn3").hide();
})

$(".js-btn1").on("click", function(){
 $(".js-table").find(".js-btn2,.js-btn3").hide();
  $(".js-table").find(".js-btn1").show();
 $(this).closest("tr").find(".js-btn2,.js-btn3").show()
  $(this).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="js-table"> 
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row1</td>
      <td>
        <button class="js-btn1"> Btn1 </button>
        <button class="js-btn2"> Btn2 </button>
         <button class="js-btn3"> Btn3 </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row2</td>
       <td>
        <button class="js-btn1"> Btn1 </button>
        <button class="js-btn2"> Btn2 </button>
         <button class="js-btn3"> Btn3 </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (Run) the below code snippet. Its simple & self explanatory. Modify it according to your needs.

Please make sure to use class, instead of id in the place of **#editAction** as you are using it on multiple rows.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myTable").on('click', 'tbody tr .editAction', function(e) {
    $('.quantity').removeClass('show');
    $('.editAction').removeClass('hide');

    $(this).addClass('hide');
    $(this).siblings('.quantity').addClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.editAction.hide {
  display: none;
}

.quantity {
  display: none;
}

.quantity.show {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <table id="myTable" width="570">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>S.no</td>
        <td>Fruit</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Action</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td><button class="editAction">Change Quantity</button> <button class="quantity">+1</button> <button class="quantity">-1</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td><button class="editAction">Change Quantity</button> <button class="quantity">+1</button> <button class="quantity">-1</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
    </html>
```